# Angular 6 minify index.html on ng build

Tags: angular, minify, google-pagespeed

In according to [Google Page Speed - Minify Resources](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources), i want minify the html of `index.html` for the build.

I can minify `index.html` manually before upload it on the live server, but the best way is minify on fly on the build, eg.:

```
ng build --prod && minify dist/index.html
```

Anyone know a solution for make it?

Comment: I don't think its possible.https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1861. May be you can try html-minifier npm package

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Actually it's possible, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11360

Comment: Last comments says "they will consider" adding this feature